# py2neo - unable to query bolt server, http error?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to use py2neo to query a Neo4J database. I can create a graph object to *connect* to the database, but when I try to run a query, I get an error:

> py2neo.packages.neo4j.v1.exceptions.ProtocolError: Server responded
>   HTTP. Make sure you are not trying to connect to the http endpoint
>   (HTTP defaults to port 7474 whereas BOLT defaults to port 7687)

I'm not sure if there's an issue with the server set up or if I'm just missing some parameter I need to set to get everything working.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from py2neo import Graph

graph = Graph("bolt://bolt.bump.dev.stratified:80", auth=("neo4j", "bump"), bolt=True)
data = graph.run("MATCH p=()-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25").data()
```

FWIW, I've also tried

```
graph = Graph("bolt://bolt.bump.dev.stratified:7687", auth=("neo4j", "bump"), bolt=True)
data = graph.run("MATCH p=()-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25").data()
```

And here's the full error message (received for either port):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/packages/neo4j/v1/session.py",
>   line 124, in session
>       session = self.session_pool.pop() IndexError: pop from an empty deque During handling of the above exception, another exception
>   occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2961, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       data = graph.run("MATCH p=()-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN p LIMIT 25").data()   File
>   "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/database/**init**.py",
>   line 731, in run
>       return self.begin(autocommit=True).run(statement, parameters, **kwparameters)   File "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/database/**init**.py",
>   line 370, in begin
>       return self.transaction_class(self, autocommit)   File "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/database/**init**.py",
>   line 1249, in **init**
>       self.session = driver.session()   File "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/packages/neo4j/v1/session.py",
>   line 126, in session
>       connection = connect(self.address, self.ssl_context, **self.config)   File "/Users/amf111/anaconda3/envs/baily/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2neo/packages/neo4j/v1/bolt.py",
>   line 486, in connect
>       "(HTTP defaults to port 7474 whereas BOLT defaults to port 7687)") py2neo.packages.neo4j.v1.exceptions.ProtocolError: Server responded
>   HTTP. Make sure you are not trying to connect to the http endpoint
>   (HTTP defaults to port 7474 whereas BOLT defaults to port 7687)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear in the message, the default bolt port is 7687 unless you modify the neo4j.conf file.

Try changing the port 80 to 7687 and try

```
graph = Graph("bolt://bolt.bump.dev.stratified:7687", auth=("neo4j", "bump"), bolt=True)
```

Comment: No, that doesn't fix it - same error message with the other port.

Comment: Can you check if following line neo4j.conf file is uncommented
`dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687`